# How correctly use a hook in a Wagtail admin?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to insert my own css into a wagtail admin page.

Сonsidering the answer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/DYeTygB_F-8 I use hook `insert_editor_css`. I've created `wagtail_hooks.py` in my app folder and added code below:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks


@hooks.register('insert_editor_css')
def editor_css():
    return format_html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{}">', static('css/admin.css'))
```

Towards to docs it should be executed but no css file inserted or even attempt to do it(errors or exceptions). I guess(maybe i'm wrong) `wagtail_hooks.py` is not being processed.

Could anybody throw me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

1. Ensure that your app was added to the [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#installed-apps) setting.
2. Ensure that your project imports `wagtail_hooks.py`. You can just put `print` somewhere on the module level or add a break point to hook function definition.
3. Ensure that you use proper hook:

   [`insert_editor_css`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) and [`insert_editor_js`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-js) used to add extra css or js *only* to the page editor interface. So your `css/admin.css` should appear on a page create or edit screen.

   If you want to add extra css or js to all admin pages you need to use [`insert_global_admin_css`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/hooks.html#insert-global-admin-css) or [`insert_global_admin_js`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/hooks.html#insert-global-admin-js).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've not added my app into `INSTALLED_APPS`